# Default placeholder is not loading in my sites in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, mysite, image

I have created a new web application inside that I created MySite and configured User Profile Service.  While accessing MySites, default placeholder is not loading.

I checked the layouts and images folder, Person Placeholder is there. The newly uploaded images are updated. I don't know why placeholder image is alone not loaded.

Please suggest me an idea to solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That could be a result that your previously uploaded Profile Picture was not successfully uploaded or removed somehow. You can try couple of things,

Hover to text **Administrator** (in your attached screenshot) and you should see **"Change Your Photo"** option there. Click that option and try to re-upload the image. That should show the most recent image you have uploaded after you are done.

Now find your Profile in User Profile Service > User Profiles and see if `PictureURL` still have the picture path.

Now run a crawl of User Profile Service and see if the image URL is replicated in AD property `thumbnailphoto` or not. If not, check if your User Profile Service account has "Replicate AD Changes" permissions on AD.

Hope that helps.